# ActiveRecord - fail to use include when using order on a calculated field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a query that I run in one of my pages. It basically goes through a transactions table, joins the payments for each transaction (many-to-one association), calculates a "balance" field on the transaction (with select), orders by this and returns the top 10.

It goes like this:

```
@high_balance_transactions = Transaction.
  joins(:payments).
  select(["transactions.*", "SUM(...) as balance"]).
  group(:id).
  having("balance < 0").
  order(:balance).
  limit(10)
```

Then, in my view, I put those in a table and need data from the payments themselves, so I end up with a lot of queries (the "N+1" problem...).

I tried to add `.includes(:payments)` to the query but got this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'balance' in 'order clause'
```

I see in the SQL that follows the error that ActiveRecord doesn't add my calculated field to the query it does, but it removed it only when I added the `includes` part. Is there any reason for that?

How can I use both a calculated field (for order and having) and include the payment data only for the records that passes all criteria?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `includes`, the `select` is ignored by Rails, that's why you get the error (I've found this in several SO question, but I don't know the reason behind this behavior).

I think you can solve your problem if you move the `SUM(...)` in the `having` and `order` clause

```
balance = 'SUM(...)'
@high_balance_transactions = Transaction.
  joins(:payments).
  includes(:payments).
  group('payments.id').
  having("#{balance} < 0").
  order(balance).
  limit(10)
```

It's not very nice in the SQL request, but It certainly won't affect the performances, the BD will compute it only once.

Comment: Thanks! it works.
Indeed not the nicest SQL but now all other queries are shown as CACHE and not Load and take 0ms.. :)